# Know what application calls my remote service

Tags: android, service, aidl

I have a service in android application. The service exposes it's interface for other applications through aidl. I would like to know the application package of the application which calls my service's methods. Is it possible?

Of course, I can store a HashMap and create a new binder for each callee, but it seems awful solution for me.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course, I can store a HashMap and create a new binder for each callee, but it seems awful solution for me.

Actually, I don't think that works. AFAIK, Android caches your `Binder`, or at least does on a per distinct `Intent` basis.

> Any ideas?

Use `getCallingUid()` and `getCallingPid()` from any of your methods in your `Binder` to see who triggered the call to that method.

Comment: Thank you, getCallingPid() works. I'm using Activity and Package Managers to get package name by PID.